# no. of solution of the equation $[x]^2+a[x]+b = 0$ is

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a$ and $b$ are odd integer. Then the no. of solution of the  equation $[x]^2+a[x]+b = 0$ is

where $[x] = $ greatest Integer function

My Try:: Let $[x] = y$. Then equation become $y^2+ay+b = 0$

Now If given equation has real Roots, Then $\displaystyle y = \frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}$

Now $a^2-4b = k^2\Leftrightarrow a^2-k^2=4b^2$. where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$

Now How can I solve after that.

Help required

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $-a$ is the sum and $b$ is the product of the roots. If the roots are integer, their sum is odd only if they have *different* parity, their product is odd only if they both are odd. Hence no solution.

Comment: awesome observation man ! simple but very good solution !

Comment: very nice observation

Answer (score 2):

equation has solution $\iff$ $y\in \mathbb Z \iff \displaystyle \frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}}{2}\in \mathbb Z \iff -a\pm \sqrt{a^2-4b}=2k :k\in \mathbb Z $ $$\iff (a+2k)^2=a^2 - 4b\iff a^2-(a+2k)^2=4b  \iff $$ $$ (-2k)(2a+2k)=4b\iff k(a+k)=b$$
if $k=2m$ and $a$ be odd then $b $ is even and if $k=2m+1$ and $a$ be odd then $b$ is even. Similarly, we have for $b$. Finally we conclude  equation has solution when $a$ or $b$ be odd.

Comment: Babak S.: thanks  and congratulation happy  eid

Comment: Happy one to you Maisam. El-Thomas-2A

Answer (score 1):

If $y := \lfloor x \rfloor$ is even, $y^2$ is even, $ay$ is even, $b$ is odd, hence $y^2 + ay + b$ is odd, so $y^2 + ay+b \ne 0$. If on the other hand, $y$ is odd, $y^2$ and $ay$ are odd also, as is $b$, so $y^2 + ay+ b$ is odd again. Hence $y^2 + ay  + b$ is an odd integer for every integer $y$. So the equation does not have any solution.